# How can I get the same effect on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I've seen a mouse-hover effect on 2 websites so far and I really like it.
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

This is the effect I'm talking about.
I'd be grateful if somebody can tell me how to get that effect on my webpage.
It only appears under your cursor when you hover over the page.

Comment: Simply see the source code of the webpage to know how they've done it.

Comment: https://whois.domaintools.com/
this is the site I first saw it in, but I can't seem to find how it's done

Comment: Here you go: http://jnicol.github.io/particleground/

Comment: Thanks @SanjeevK you can add it as an answer so I can mark it answered :))

Comment: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Comment: Why was this question marked as "not focused"? this is a good question

Answer (score 1):

- Simply, Go to the webpage you wanted to Copy it's effects or anything from it
- Right click, View page source 
  If the effect is made by Css, you will find it in stylesheets tab 
  If it's using jQuery/Js, Search the `head` for `<script>` , Read them and copy the effect (assuming that you understand js/jquery 
  For more simplicity, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), open it and just point the cursor at the item you want to see it's source.
  But, actually 
  You can find it at github [Here](https://github.com/jnicol/particleground) 
  Change what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The site you have linked in the comments uses the [HTML canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) element. But You can simply use already existing libraries for that effect.

Examples mentioned in the comments:

- http://jnicol.github.io/particleground/
- http://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js